# Mule / AMQP / RabbitMQ: Trying to send to the default exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, mule, amqp

Using Mule 3.4 with the AMQP Transport plugin and RabbitMQ, I am trying to send a message to the default AMQP exchange.  The documentation for the exchangeName attribute states "leave blank or omit for the default exchange".  However if I (a) omit it, like so:

```
<amqp:outbound-endpoint routingKey="my.queue" connector-ref="amqpDefaultConnector" />
```

Then I get the error message:

> Element amqp:outbound-endpoint{connector-ref=amqpDefaultConnector,
>   name=.test:outbound-endpoint.17, routingKey=process.task.complete}
>   must have all attributes for one of the sets: [address] [ref]
>   [queueName] [exchangeName] [exchangeName, queueName].

Which seems to indicate that it is not valid to omit the attribute. However, if I (b) provide it but leave it blank, like so:

```
<amqp:outbound-endpoint exchangeName="" routingKey="my.queue" connector-ref="amqpDefaultConnector" />
```

then I get the error message:

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected authority at index 7: amqp://

I believe that the rest of my configuration and setup is correct, as using a named exchange works as expected.   Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dispatch to the default exchange, you need to pass the queue name in `queueName` not `routingKey`:

```
<amqp:outbound-endpoint exchangeName=""
                        queueName="my.queue"
                        connector-ref="amqpDefaultConnector" />
```

Comment: Thanks David!  That seems to work!  But it is definitely non intuitive based on standard AMQP terminology, in which you would always expect to publish to exchanges and read from queues -- not publish to a queue -- even though this is what you do in effect when publishing to the default exchange using a routing key.  I suspect I will not be the last one to try using a routing key here; maybe in a future release you can make the routingKey and queueName options behave the same way.

Comment: I know this isn't perfect as far as AMQP's concepts are concerned, this was a compromise to satisfy with the constraints of XSD and configuration parsing. Glad it works anyway :)